# Modify frame src by calling Javascript method

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I have a requirement where I need to modify Frame `src` by calling JavaScript method.

But string manipulation inside `src` tag is not working.

This code works:

```
<frame name="dashBoardLeftFrame" target="dashBoardContents" src="javascript:window.top.encodeURIComponent('blank.html')" >
```

But This doesn't. And I need to implement this. :(

```
<frame name="dashBoardLeftFrame" target="dashBoardContents" src="requestDelegateAct.do?delegateAction=javascript:window.top.encodeURIComponent('blank.html')" />
```

In the end I need my src to be `requestDelegateAct.do?delegateAction=(some encoded string)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: 
leave the `src` empty in HTML

```
<frame name="dashBoardLeftFrame" target="dashBoardContents" src="">
```

and add JavaScript:

```
var frame = document.getElementsByName("dashBoardLeftFrame")[0];
frame.src = "requestDelegateAct.do?delegateAction=" + someEncodedString;
```

Comment: Actually I need to do this type of changes in multiple places.. So I was hoping i would be great if i can do this inside src itself.

Comment: You could add an extra attribute to the HTML `<frame name="dashBoardLeftFrame" data-encodedstring="1234">` on every occurrence and then use that value in the JavaScript. Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

See this http://influxhostserver.com/test.php might help you

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>

<button id="change"  value="change" style="width:100px;height:100px" >Change</button>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#change").click(function(){
            $('#iframe').attr('src','test.php');
        });
    });
</script>
```